# Pycharm: Error "Cannot perform Refactoring. Function is not under the source root"

Tags: pycharm

I am using pycharm 4.0.4 on windows 8 and my project structure is as follows:

```
my_django_project (pycharm content root)
-lib
-docs
-scripts (virtualenv)
-my_project (pycharm source root)
 -tempaltes
 -management
 -models.py
 -views.py
 etc....
```

pycharm project interpreter:

```
2.7.2 virualenv at c:\path\to\my_django_project
```

I am trying to perform a change signature refactor and a method in a class in my models.py file.

With the project interpreter set as above rename refactorings work perfectly but, change signature results in `Cannot perform Refactoring. Function is not under the source root"`

If I change pycharm project interpreter to:

```
2.7.2 virualenv at c:\Python27\python.exe
```

And all refactorings work but, this is not my virtualenv.  What am i doing wrong?  Seems wrong having to switch out of the virtualenv in order to refactor.

Any ideas welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have your project root in the list of interpreter paths (`Settings| Project Interpreter| Press Cogwheel| More| Show paths for the selected interpreter`)?

If yes, it's the following known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9285.

You can follow it for updates, see howto: http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23368682.

Comment: Link is broken, do you mind sharing the solution here ? Thanks !

Answer (score 7):

Try this: `Settings -> Project Structure -> Add Content Root`, then select the folder you want to use. This fixed my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution I am using as of pycharm 2023.1 (Build #PY-231.8109.197, built on March 29, 2023) is to rename the project dir to something other than the package name used in pyproject.toml.

E.g. the dir could be 'pj_package-name' and in pyproject.toml I have `name = 'package-name'`

Thank you PyTony for giving me the right hint.